# Как грамотно организовать данные для функции?

Tags: python, функции

В моем модуле есть процедура, выполняющая создание прописи. Она принимает несколько аргументов - это данные, различные при каждом запуске программы. Но есть ещё данные по типу межстрочного интервала, размера страницы прописи и т.д. То есть те данные, которые являются как бы константами, но если вдруг понадобиться начать создавать прописи другого размера (то есть для другого проекта; другой кейс), было бы удобнее просто изменить лишь этот параметр, вместо переписывания кода.

Вот данная функция

```
def make_prescription(font_name, lang, save_path):
    # ____________________________________________________
    sheet_size = (2480, 3508)
    up_margin = 190
    bottom_margin = 50
    line_height = 2
    letter_min_size = 75  # Данные "костанты"
    letters_sets = {
        "eng": "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
        "rus": "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя",
    }
    # ____________________________________________________
    # Алгоритм создания прописи
    pass
```

Где лучше хранить значения sheet_size, ..., letters_sets? Оставить в теле функции, вынести в начало модуля, в аргументы, в файл какой-нибудь или есть решение получше?

Comment: задайте их именованными аргументами def make_prescription(font_name, lang, save_path, sheet_size = (2480, 3508), up_margin = 190, etc.):

Comment: Не хочу показаться занудным, но вроде как по clean code'у в функции не должно быть более 4 аргументов, а тут у меня получится 9

Comment: @Jack_oS, (забыл добавить упоминание в прошлом комменте)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном сценарии лучше всего на мой взгляд подошёл бы какой-нибудь файл конфигурации. Например, в виде json-файла, из которого ваш модуль читал бы словарь с набором параметров.

В принципе, есть и специальные библиотеки для работы с конфигурационными файлами, но так в общем json довольно удобен и понятен как для того, кто будет его редактировать вручную (в любом текстовом редакторе), также его довольно просто читать и обрабатывать в программе на питоне .

Comment: лично я предпочитаю YAML в качестве формата хранения файлов конфигурации - он лаконичнее и легче читается (более "human friendly") ;)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Если бы этот модуль был итоговым продуктом, то я бы без сомнений создал бы файл конфигурации, но ведь это лишь составная часть моей программы. Несмотря на это вы все равно считаете, что в моем случае лучшее решение - использовать конфиг?

Comment: @Paitor Мне кажется, нужно спросить у того, кто будет использовать ваш модуль, как ему будет удобнее его конфирурировать через файл конфигурации, через код или может ещё как-то. Бывает и в БД конфиг пишут, всяко бывает.